# Creating hashtable in Python 3 for my class

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a class containing several members.

I would like to create hash table, containing 'objects' of this class and to be able to search (use the hashmap :) )

As I know I should overload the `__eq__` operator

what should I go from there?

I wasn't able to find any references for creating an hash table in python ... especially not for 'my class'

Comment: It is called a python `dict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the [`.__hash__()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) as well as the `.__eq__()` method.

The method should return an integer, and for any two objects where `.__eq__()` returns `True`, `.__hash__()` *must* return the same integer value.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the built-in [`hash()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) on each and every attribute of your instance that makes it unique, and return the XORed result of those values.

Example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return self.bar == other.bar and self.baz == other.baz
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.bar) ^ hash(self.baz)
```

Demo:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo('ham', 'eggs')
>>> foo2 = Foo('ham', 'eggs')
>>> foo3 = Foo('spam', 'vikings')
>>> foo1 == foo2
True
>>> foo1 == foo3
False
>>> hash(foo1)
1838536788654183919
>>> hash(foo1) == hash(foo2)
True
>>> hash(foo1) == hash(foo3)
False
>>> mapping = {}
>>> mapping[foo1] = 'Monty Python'
>>> foo1 in mapping
True
>>> foo2 in mapping
True
>>> foo3 in mapping
False
>>> mapping[foo2]
'Monty Python'
```

Comment: @SagiLow: The python `dict` *is* a hashmap under the hood and insertion and lookup on those has O(1) complexity. All `__hash__` does is make it possible for you to use your custom type as a key. We did not create the hash table itself here.